# Determine whether a C# Record implements custom Equality comparison by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, record, equality

Is it possible to know whether a Record type has a custom implementation of the `Equals` method using reflection?

For example, with the following code:

```
public sealed record A
{
    public long Id { get; init; }
}

public sealed record B
{
    public string Name { get; init; }

    public bool Equals(B other) => StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(this.Name, other.Name); 
    public override int GetHashCode() => StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(this.Name);
}
```

I would like a method which could return:

```
HasCustomEqualityImplementation(typeof(A)); // false
HasCustomEqualityImplementation(typeof(B)); // true
```

It does not seem obvious, as the compiler automatically generates an `Equals` method for record `A`, and I didn't find a way to differentiate it from the explicit implementation from record `B`, but I may have missed something.

Comment: A better question is what you hope to accomplish with this. Usually such distinctions (where useful at all) should be made on the source level, with something like Roslyn. Doing it at runtime is either not possible (as I suspect it is in this case) or not useful, since there's no way to know what's happening in the actual implementation unless you fancy decompiling IL.

Comment: Small question - why do you need this? Are you sure you need this at runtime? I'm pretty much sure it is not possible to achieve this via reflection - compiler does not emit extra info for this methods. If you need this info at compile time - you can use Roslyn code analyzer. Or using Roslyn API you can write a source generator which will generate corresponding methods. My small [pet project](https://github.com/gurustron/default-record-ctor) which plays with some code generation around records can be useful.

Comment: It's kind of hacky but you can rely on the `NullableContextAttribute` that is being applied by the compiler on the generated method only. But again, not recommended as the implementation may change in different compiler versions.

Comment: I understand this should not be needed in classical situations; the context here is a method which compares an expected method output with the actual output for unit tests. If the type has a custom explicit implementation of "Equals", we use it, otherwise we're performing a comparison of all property values, except some specified properties to ignore (ex: ids or dates which depend on the execution context). This broke when I switched classes to records, as the comparison is now using the default record's "Equals" which can't ignore the specified properties

Comment: Of course, we can still set the properties to ignore to their default values before the comparison, but I was investigating whether there was a way to preseve the previous behaviour

Comment: @haim770: you can leave out the "kind of". Nullable annotations are orthogonal to records; there is literally no guarantee the presence of `NullableContextAttribute` proves the method is compiler-generated, nor does its absence prove it's *not* compiler-generated. Using this is just setting yourself up for new trouble down the line.

Comment: @JulienBarrau: Consider something like Fluent Assertions' `Should().BeEquivalentTo()`, which is very customizable. Even then, regardless of how you go about it, you should probably prefer having *one* method of comparing objects regardless of whether or not `.Equals()` happens to be implemented, otherwise you're just setting your tests up for instability. If the `.Equals()` implementation cannot be expected to tell you if things are equal for your tastes in *some* cases, it should probably be ignored in *all* cases.